# create jlabel on fly

Tags: java, swing

How can I configure which `JLabel` is pressed?

```
String [] a={"lable1","label2"};
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    JLabel lb=new JLabel("");
    lb.setText(a[i]);
    scanPanel.add(lb);
    add(scanPanel);
    lb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //HERE I NEED THE SOURCE NAME:)
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
    }
});
```

Comment: Ouch that post is hard to read!  My eyes are burning!

Comment: I'm sure my eyes would be bleeding too if I were in a hovercraft full of eels.

Comment: You edited your code and you still forgot the first and last line. How hard is it to actually look at your question and make sure everything is readable???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get one free answer. If you can't take the time to format a question properly even after you've been asked to so I'm not going to waste time helping.

Still not sure what the "source name" is, but I'll make a wild guess:

```
JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
System.out.println(label.getText());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. Next I will care actually I didn't know how to formate the question.